# how to create coverflow in corona?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

i am new corona sdk and interest to work in corona sdk. i didn't know to create a cover flow like the Images in below. any one me help to like that
thank you
[image: cover flow]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given where you are right now, your question is too complex to be answered in a single StackOverflow answer. I will instead give you the high-level steps you need to follow.

1. Start by learning the Lua language, if you don't know it already. [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/) is a good free resource.
2. The next step is learning how to put an image on the screen with Corona.
3. Then learn how to put several images on the screen with Corona.
4. Then learn how to make them "scroll left and right", using the finger.
5. You will also want to learn how to make each picture "react" to a touch event.
6. Finally, learn how to "add perspective" to an image, so you can do the effects on the side.

And then you will have a working cover flow.

Try each step separatedly. If you get stuck in one step, open a new question for it. For example, if you get stuck on step 3, create a question similar to this one:

> **How do I scroll left/right a gallery of images in Corona SDK?**
>
> I'm trying to create a cover flow in Corona SDK. I'm stuck trying to
>   make images scroll left and right. I have tried this code [put code
>   here] but it doesn't work because instead I see [what you see]. I
>   would like it to [what you want it to do instead]

Good luck!

Comment: hai kikito. And i konw how add the images in corona and i want know do this type of animation.did you help me do to that of animation